# VB.NET Text From Specific HTML Class

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, httpwebrequest, html

I am working on a dictionary app in vb.net and need help finding the definitions. I know how to look up the HTML code of the website through HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse and ReadtoEnd(), but I want just the definition text from Dictionary.com. The class where the text is in in

```
<div class="body">
```

but I just dont know how to access all the displayed text from it.

CODE:

```
Private Sub Search()
    Label3.Text = TextBox1.Text
    searchurl = String.Format("http://www.dictionary.reference.com/browse/{0}?s=t", TextBox1.Text)
    request = HttpWebRequest.Create(searchurl)
    response = request.GetResponse
    sr = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

    htmltext = sr.ReadToEnd.ToString


    RichTextBox1.Text = htmltext

End Sub
```

Comment: You'll probably find it easiest to load the result into something that can work with XML (since HTML is XML). Then use whatever features provided by that library to get to the "node" you want.

Comment: Try the Html Agility pack, makes parsing html easy  http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack